# Empty hash as default parameter turning into an Array?

Tags: ruby

A parameter defaulted to an empty hash `attrs={}` returns an error:

```
can't convert Array into Hash
(TypeError)
```

I've tried this on Ruby versions 1.8.6, 1.8.7 and 1.9.1. A hash will be passed to `attrs`.

```
class Category < Object   

  attr_accessor :attributes  
  attr_accessor :rel_attrs  
  attr_accessor :cls_str

  def initialize (term='',title='', attrs={}, scheme = '', rel=[], cls_str='')

    @attributes ={}
    @attributes['scheme']  = scheme
    @attributes['term']    = term
    @attributes['title']   = title
    @attributes['related'] = rel
    @cls_str = cls_str

    if not attrs.empty?
       @attributes.update attrs
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you invoking the initialize  method or what are the parameters which are you passing while creating instance of Category?

Comment: Show the file name and the line of where the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

- You don't have to inherit from `Object`.
- `if not` can more idiomatically be expressed as `unless`.
- Making the `attrs` hash the last argument has the advantage that you can leave off the `{}` around the hash elements when calling `Category.new`. You can **not** do this if the hash is the middle, so it would make sense to show us your call to `Category.new`.

I changed your code accordingly:

```
class Category 

  attr_accessor :attributes
  attr_accessor :rel_attrs  
  attr_accessor :cls_str

  def initialize (term='',title='', scheme = '', rel=[], cls_str='', attrs={})

    @attributes ={}
    @attributes['scheme']  = scheme
    @attributes['term']    = term
    @attributes['title']   = title
    @attributes['related'] = rel
    @cls_str = cls_str

    @attributes.update(attrs) unless attrs.empty?
  end
end
```

Here's how you call it:

```
>> c = Category.new("term", "title", "scheme", [1,2,3], 'cls_string', :foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux') 
#=> #<Category:0x00000100b7bff0 @attributes={"scheme"=>"scheme", "term"=>"term", "title"=>"title", "related"=>[1, 2, 3], :foo=>"bar", :baz=>"qux"}, cls_str"cls_string"
>> c.attributes 
#=> {"scheme"=>"scheme", "term"=>"term", "title"=>"title", "related"=>[1, 2, 3], :foo=>"bar", :baz=>"qux"}
```

This obviously has the problem that all other optional arguments have to be specified in order to be able to specify `attrs`. If you don't want this, move `attrs` back to the middle of the argument list and make sure to include the `{}` in the call. Or even better, make the whole argument list a hash and merge it with the defaults args. Something like

```
 class Category(opts = {})
   # stuff skipped
   @options = { :bla => 'foo', :bar => 'baz'}.merge(opts)
   # more stuff skipped
 end
```

Comment: Also, I'd advice to simplify the method signature, IMO it looks pretty bad. It's sane common practive to move all optional arguments to the options hash.

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested in the last paragraph and code snippet :-)

Comment: @Micahel. oh, sorry, I didn't see it.

Comment: thanks guys, I inherited this code.. before anyone replied I rewrote the interfaces.. I had 20+ others